# Chain Watir commands

Tags: ruby, watir

As an example, I’d like to get my browser’s user agent as output from http://www.useragentstring.com/ and store it in a variable. Currently, I can do it in multiple lines

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
b.goto('http://www.useragentstring.com/')
agent = b.textarea.text
b.close
```

Ideally, I’d like to do it in a single line. Something like

```
require 'watir'
agent = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome).goto('http://www.useragentstring.com/').textarea.text
```

But that fails with

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `textarea' for "http://www.useragentstring.com/":String`
```

So while the `goto` part works, the rest doesn’t. Since `watir` lets us do things like `wait_until_present.click`, I’m hoping there’s some way to chain these methods as well. Is this even possible?

Comment: [`goto`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/0.6.11/Watir/Browser#goto-instance_method) doesn't return `self`, so I don't see how you chain to it.  A method like [`wait_until`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Waitable#wait_until-instance_method) can be chained (e.g. `wait_until_present.click`) because it does return `self`.

Comment: Goto doesn't return the self, Goto return the uri, uri is the string So you can't call the method `textarea` there.

Comment: I would discourage this just on the basis of good coding practices regarding clean readable code.   There is no advantage (that I can see anyway) in doing that in a single line, and it makes it substantially more difficult to follow what the code does.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden The line is relatively short and easy to follow. Since this would be a technique that I would use as a one-off in several scripts, one line makes it easier to copy around and to ignore in the context of the rest of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make anything chain-able by using the `tap` method. As described by the [Ruby Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-tap):

> Yields self to the block, and then returns self. The primary purpose
>   of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform
>   operations on intermediate results within the chain.

That means that you can use `tap` to call `goto` and still have the `Watir::Browser` instance for calling `textarea`:

```
agent = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome).tap{ |b| b.goto('http://www.useragentstring.com/') }.textarea.text
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. I’ll accept the answer, though it seems like I won’t be able to use it, since I also need to `.close` the browser. I can nest calls to `tap` and it works, but then `.close` will return `true`, not the `agent`. Still worth it to learn about `tap`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the reason for wanting a single-line? If you just want to see a single line in your file, you could just take your original multiple line answer and put them on a single line separated by semi-colons.

Comment: Extraordinary Justin Ko !

Comment: @JustinKo See [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880460/chain-watir-commands?noredirect=1#comment74830012_43880460). I was also interested in this for learning purposes. In that regard it was a huge success, since I learned something new about ruby itself, not just watir.

Answer (score 1):

Though `goto` method does not support chaining you can make your custom method for `Watir::Browser` like following

```
class Watir::Browser
  def chain_goto(url)
    goto(url)
    self
  end
end
```

Then you can use that like
    `Watir::Browser.new(:firefox).chain_goto('http://www.useragentstring.com/').textarea.text`.

So the complete code will be like

```
require 'watir'

class Watir::Browser
  def chain_goto(url)
    goto(url)
    self
  end
end

b = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox).chain_goto('http://www.useragentstring.com/'.textarea.text
```

Comment: Though this is an ingenious solution, then we’re just moving the extra lines somewhere else, which somewhat defeats the purpose. Will still upvote since it’s technically correct.